# Is this decision correct? PL/SQL

Tags: database, plsql

Can anyone help me with the following task:
Create a procedure SectionCount(instructor_ID) that, according to the instructor's ID, displays the numbers of those of its sections with the largest number of students enrolled. Display appropriate messages if an instructor with such an ID does not exist or if there are no sections to lead. Add a block to handle the necessary exceptions.

my solution is the following..whether it is correct:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_function_name(i_student_id NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER AS v_sections_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(SECTION_ID) into v_sections_count FROM ENROLLMENT WHERE STUDENT_ID = i_student_id;
IF v_sections_count > 3 THEN
RETURN -1;
ELSE 
RETURN v_sections_count;
END IF;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error occured.');
RETURN -2;
END;
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Best way to find out if it is working is... testing. Did you do that ? There is no code for "Display appropriate messages if..." so that is missing but you probably figured that out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion or two, if I may.

- always use table's alias when referencing columns. In your case, that's only one table but - often you have to "fix" a query and add yet another table, and then you don't know which column belongs to which table and have to add aliases anyway.
- try to use only one `RETURN` per function (two, if there's an exception handling section - as in your function) because you might do *something wrong* in code logic and `RETURN` (i.e. *terminate* further execution) although you didn't actually want to do that. Instead, add a new variable which will be used to "calculate" the return value (such as `retval` in code I posted); then return its value
- `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` is OK for debugging; nobody else will ever see it, because end users won't call that function from SQL*Plus (or other tools which are capable of displaying that message). For example, it (`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`) won't raise error in Oracle Apex or Oracle Forms, but you won't see anything.

  - Also, add `SQLERRM` which will actually *show* you which error happened. Info "an error occurred" isn't very descriptive

So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_function_name (i_student_id NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER 
AS 
  v_sections_count NUMBER;
  retval           NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(e.section_id) 
    INTO v_sections_count 
    FROM enrollment e
   WHERE e.student_id = i_student_id;

  retval := CASE WHEN v_sections_count > 3 then -1
                 ELSE v_sections_count 
            END;

  RETURN retval;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error occured: ' || SQLERRM);
    retval := -2;
    RETURN retval;
END your_function_name ;
```